# How much load it is?

Tags: jmeter

I have tried but have a doubt that whether the below-mentioned specification is equivalent to 4000load or not.
the number of threads-100,
ramp-up period-10 secs,
loop count- 40, then
which is equal to how much load??

Answer (score 0):

You are loading 100 concurrent threads, the loops just adds more execution time.

So it isn't equivalent to 4000 concurrent threads hitting your server

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by `4000load`, your test will send 4000 requests per each [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) which is in your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) as fast as it can. The actual test duration will depend on your application response time but will not be less than 10 seconds.

You might want to take a look at [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond) and [Server Hits per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond) charts to see how many requests your configuration delivers, both charts can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Also you can generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which will have consolidated aggregate view of your test results.